# False positive received on SecKeyRawVerify in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am signing a JWT with RSASHA-256 and trying to verify it on my iOS SDK.

When sending the complete data, the verification pass.

However, when tampering with the data received, I still receive a false positive.

Adding the code here:

```
//
//  NSData+VerifySignature.m
//  InsertFramework
//
//  Created by yaniv1 on 1/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Insert. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NSData+VerifySignature.h"
#import "IIOStringEncoder.h"
#import "IIOLog.h"
#import "IIORSA.h"

@implementation NSData (VerifySignature)

-(NSArray *)createComponents{
    NSString *data =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *components = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if (!components || [components count] != 3) {
    IIOErrorLog(@"Invalid JWT received for verification");
    return nil;
}

return components;
}

-(NSData *)verifySignature:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)urlResponse {

//Getting response header content-type and checking if it is jwt
NSString *contentType = [[[urlResponse allHeaderFields][@"Content-Type"] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:0];

if (![contentType isEqualToString:@"insert/jwt"])
{
    return nil;
}

NSArray *signatureComponents = [self createComponents];
if (!signatureComponents) {
    return nil;
}

//JWT is seperated into his 3 components
NSString *header = signatureComponents[0];
NSString *payload = signatureComponents[1];
NSString *signature = signatureComponents[2];

//Turining signature received in base64 to base64UrlEncoded
NSData *base64UrlEncodedSig = [IIOStringEncoder dataWithBase64UrlEncodedString:signature];

SecKeyRef pKey = [IIORSA addPublicKey];
if (!pKey) {
    IIOErrorLog(@"Failed to create public key, which results in verification failure");
    return nil;
}

//Creating the data to verify the signature, meaning the header.payload
NSString *headerAndPayload = [[header stringByAppendingString:@"."] stringByAppendingString:payload];
NSData *dataHeaderAndPayload = [headerAndPayload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Verify the signature. For further details, go to
BOOL status = SecKeyRawVerify (pKey,
                      kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1,
                      (const uint8_t *)[dataHeaderAndPayload bytes],
                      (size_t)[dataHeaderAndPayload length],
                      (const uint8_t *)[base64UrlEncodedSig bytes],
                      (size_t)[base64UrlEncodedSig length]
                      );

if (!status) {
    IIOErrorLog(@"Failed to verify signature");
    return nil;
}

NSData *payloadDecodedData = [[NSData alloc]   initWithBase64EncodedString:payload options:0];

    return payloadDecodedData;
}

@end
```

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

That method doesn't return `BOOL`.  See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyRawVerify):

```
OSStatus SecKeyRawVerify(SecKeyRef key,
    SecPadding padding,
    const uint8_t *signedData,
    size_t signedDataLen,
    const uint8_t *sig,
    size_t sigLen);
```

Comment: There was someone faster than me :)